# how to deserialize json response to .net object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

```
responsestring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
 ClassifierResponse Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassifierResponse>(responsestring);
```

my json response is

```
{
  "resultList": [  
    {  
      "modelId": 11,  
      "modelName": "indves12",  
      "modelLang": "US",  
      "modelVersion": 5,  
      "scoreMap": {  
        "individual": 0.401956,  
        "vessel": 0.598043  
      },  
      "bestCategory": "vessel"  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

And im getting this error :
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Can you show the class `ClassifierResponse`?

Comment: added the class now to the question .@vernou

Comment: should i add resultlist to deserialize like   ClassifierResponse<ResultList> Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassifierResponse<ResultList>>(responsestring);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class

```
public class ClassifierResponse
{
    public List<ResultList> ResultList { get; set; }
}
 
public class ResultList 
{ 
    public int ModelId {get; set;}
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ModelLang { get; set; }
    public int ModelVersion { get; set; }
    public Scoremap Scoremap { get; set;}
    public string BestCategory { get; set; }
}
public class Scoremap 
{
    public double Individual{ get; set; }
    public double Vessel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Try to type some text to describe the change you made because it won't be obvious in this that the Scoremap was changed from a generic ```List<T>``` to a single object.

Comment: should i deserailize resultlist ?@Rodel P.Ocfemia

Comment: I am getting the response but im not able to access the properties inside response. I was trying like this.   Response.Resultlist.